# Directadmin interface Virtual Host Httpd.conf Customization

Tags: apache, https, httpd.conf, directadmin

How add custom httpd.conf code to the VirtualHosts of a domain in the directadmin interface?

I need to add this lines to redirect http to https on my domains in the VirtualHost Port 80 and 443:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.example.com
      Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
      # Use HTTP Strict Transport Security to force client to use secure connections only
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"

      # Further Configuration goes here
      [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

**I've solve it with this htaccess redirect:**

```
# Redirect if http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# set header if https
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why are you trying this with httpd configuration. You need to update .htaccess file to redirect your all HTTP traffic to HTTPS

Try with following .htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've solve it with a similar redirect. I've edited the answer.